# Is a widget on screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-state

I want to monitor which parts of my app the users interact with the most. So, I'm planning to create a custom widget that records and logs how long it is on the screen for, and how many times it gets pressed.

My question is, is there a way to check if a widget is currently displayed on the screen at a given moment. For example, the page might consist of a column of Card widgets, and I want to know which cards are on the screen to know how much time users spend interacting with it.

I might be over-complicating stuff, if there's a package  you know of that aims to track user interaction with the app, please share that as well!

Comment: [`package:visibikity_detector`](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector) should help you get started.